# How to call multiple web services in wso2 sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a class mediator in sequence which will have list of requests.
Now I need to iterate the list of request and send it to a defined end point.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Call Mediator** to call multiple web services in a single sequence.

See [Call Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Call+Mediator) for details.

You can do iterate your messages using **Iterate mediator**.
See [Iterate Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Iterate+Mediator) for details.

Thanks